# Display data as simple line graph - react native

Tags: react-native

**i want to display the data as line graph instead of text.**

i used react-native-charts-wrapper for graph please help me out

```js
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(`res: ${JSON.stringify(res['activities-distance'])}`);   
        this.setState({
          result:res['activities-distance']});
  })
  } 
  render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>All-Day Activity</Text>
    <Button title="CHECK STEPS" onPress{()=>this.connectFitbit()}/>
    
    <FlatList
  data={this.state.result}
  renderItem={
    ({item}) => <View>
                <Text>DATE : {item.dateTime}</Text>
                <Text>STEPS :{item.value}</Text>
                </View>
  } 
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => {return index+item}}/>

  </View>
```